# Dzi Viewer using CPP

Tags: deepzoom, openseadragon, vips

I am looking for a Deep Zoom Image (DZI) viewer in CPP.
Currently, we have a viewer designed in javascript (Open Seadragon), java, and C# for the dzi images. 
I am looking for the open-source viewer that can be integrated in my CPP application.

Answer (score 1):

I made a tiny example program that displays a [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) image in a window:

https://github.com/libvips/vipsdisp-tiny

It's about 300 lines for the entire thing. It uses gtk+3, but it should be simple to adapt for other toolkits.

The cool thing is that it doesn't just display an image, it displays the end of a libvips pipeline, and it does it asynchronously. You can scroll around the image and the display will be updated in the background by a threadpool as chunks of the image are computed.

For your application, you could use [`vips_arrayjoin()`](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/libvips-conversion.html#vips-arrayjoin) to join up the tiles of the DZI image, then display the output of arrayjoin in the window.

There's a more complete image viewer here:

https://github.com/jcupitt/vipsdisp

Though I still haven't got around to finishing it, unfortunately.